# Extending HTMLElement interface with classes

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I would like to extend the HTMLElement interface with a custom object on a custom property. Is that even possible?

This is what I've got:

```
if (typeof HTMLElement.prototype.classList === "undefined") {
    HTMLElement.prototype.classList = function ClassList() { return this.className.split(' '); };
    HTMLElement.classList.prototype.add = function(name) {
        if (classList.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        classList[classList.length] = name;
        this.className = classList.join(' ');
    };
    HTMLElement.classList.prototype.remove = function(name) {
        var index = classList.indexOf(name);
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.className = classList.splice(index + 1, 1).join(' ');
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you a good idea about what I need.

I want to implement my own `classList` functionality for IE9.
In IE, this would result in undefined and would throw an error.

```
element.classList.add('fadeIn');
```

Is there a simple way to implement this?

**EDIT**

I've been toying around with this for a while but my knowledge isn't good enough yet to understand exactly what's going on. I still have to call `document.getElementById('whatever').classList()` to avoid getting "undefined". I would love to be able to call classList without braces (if the browser doesn't support classList, of course)

Comment: You’re checking for `classlist` but you’re implementing `classList`. Those are not the same.

Comment: Right... that was just a typo, the original question remains tho :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a getter (a function that can be invoked without parentheses), use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Works in IE9.

```
function getClassList()
{
    var element = this;
    var classList = this.className.split(' ');
    classList.add = function(name) {
        if (classList.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        classList.push(name);
        element.className = classList.join(' ');
    };
    classList.remove = function(name) {
        var index = classList.indexOf(name);
        if (index !== -1) {
            classList.splice(index, 1);
            element.className = classList.join(' ');
        }
    };
    return classList;
}

Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'classList', { get: getClassList });
```

Comment: I'll verify when I get home, but this is probably it. I'm at work right now and the following command seems to work on IE9: `Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'classList', { value: {}});`

Comment: @RobbieVercammen I tested this and fixed it. Particularly, since `classList` is an array, it's not convenient to add the `add` and `remove` methods directly to the prototype (which is `Array.prototype`). There are however [polyfills](https://github.com/remy/polyfills) that use custom objects rather than an array for the `classList` (not tested).

Comment: Always happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've setup the prototype wrong.

You should be assigning `classList` to `HTMLElement.prototype`, not directly on `HTMLElement` itself.

To access it like it works natively, you could set it up like so...

```
HTMLElement.prototype.classList = function()
  // ...
};

HTMLElement.prototype.classList.add = function()
  // ...
};

HTMLElement.prototype.classList.remove = function()
  // ...
};
```

Comment: You're right but this doesn't solve the question. I still have to call `document.getElementById('whatever').classList()` to avoid getting "undefined". I would love to be able to call classList without braces.

Comment: @RobbieVercammen Assign them directly to that function, not its prototype.  e.g. `HTMLElement.prototype.classList.add = /* your function */`

Comment: I think I may have tried that before, I'll try your suggestion when I get home