# Do I inherit from Element when I extend the HTMLElement interface?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, interface

JS borrows the model of classes, interfaces and objects from other languages, but has its own style of doing the things.

[image]

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)is calling the `HTMLElement` an interface. In inherits from `Element`, which is a class in turn. This would not work in Java.

```js
class ContentCardExample extends HTMLElement {
```

I find [this example](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/frontend/custom-ui/custom-card/) of javascript, that does extend the interface. In Java an interface would be implemented. This brings up a bunch of questions for me.

1.) Do I inherit the methods from `Element` when I extend `HTMLElement` or are they lost?

2.) If so, is `HTMLElement` a class and the wording of an interface is just an inaccuracy?

3.) Does `HTMLElement` add new methods, that can use or does it force me to implement methods in sense of a Java interface?

This question is related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726625/extending-htmlelement-interface-with-classes) which expresses the problem in terms of prototypes, thought. At least in syntax it is not the same problem.

Comment: an "interface" in the documentation sense is basically what `abstract class` is in Java. It defines methods and inherits things, you just won't get an instance of it.

Comment: Interface just tells me, that I can't make an instance of the class?

Comment: Essentially - yes. Do note, that it's only so *in this context* as in, the DOM API specifications. There aren't really "interfaces" elsewhere until you get to TypeScript. And there an interface acts a lot more like Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.) Do I inherit the methods from Element when I extend HTMLElement or are they lost?

Your new subclass inherits them, via the prototype chain.

> 2.) If so, is HTMLElement a class and the wording of an interface is just an inaccuracy?

It's not inaccurate, it's a documentation/specification concept. What you have at runtime is a concrete implementation of that interface provided by the host environment (the browser's DOM implementation, in this case).

> 3.) Does HTMLElement add new methods, that can use or does it force me to implement methods in sense of a Java interface?

The methods are provided, again via the prototype chain. For example, `click` is a method added by `HTMLElement` (it doesn't exist on `Element`). You can see that a subclass inherits it:

```js
// `click` isn't part of `Element`
console.log("click" in Element.prototype);      // false

// It's provided by `HTMLElement`
console.log("click" in HTMLElement.prototype);  // true

// If we define our own element type extending `HTMLElement`...
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
}
customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
// ...and create an instance of it...
const x = document.createElement("my-element");
// ...our custom element instance inherits from `HTMLElement`:
console.log(x instanceof HTMLElement);          // true
// ...and via that from `Element`:
console.log(x instanceof MyElement);            // true
// ...and so it has `click`:
console.log(typeof x.click);                    // "function"
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. Let's phrase Java has a very special notion of the term interface.